# Running services in developer options is missing

Tags: applications, developer-options, background-process

I want to check the apps that are running in the background to stop them.
Android 10
MIUI 12
redmi note 7s (NOT ROOTED)

i tried a lot of apps from playstore they doesn't seem to work properly (Doesn't show the amount of ram used and not able to force close or end the background apps).

I also tried the developer options but there was NO option for "running services" in the developer options, is there a way to enable this in developer options.

Comment: How about something like this? https://i.stack.imgur.com/rwaud.jpg